# Retorno de campo em laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho o seguinte campo guardado em minha base de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao tentar retornar ele na view pelo `Laravel 5.2` ele está retornando somente o `45` o restante não está.

o campo está definido assim no banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém outros campos como telefone estão retornando corretamente.

Alguém sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: teria um trecho do teu código para demonstrar como está realizando a requisição ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo que você remova a pontuação antes de armazenar estes valores, vai facilitar as comparações, as buscas e qualquer outra operação que envolva esta coluna.

Para resolver o seu problema, você pode utilizar o `attribute casting` do eloquent model. Dentro da sua classe modelo, tente definir a propriedade `casts` como um `array`, e dentro dela o seu campo como `string`, por exemplo:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'cnpj' => 'string',
];
```

Se mesmo assim não resolver, tente modificar o seu migration para utilizar o método `string`, dessa forma:

```
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {

    ....

    $table->string('cnpj', 14)->nullable();

    ....

}
```

Para mais informações você pode visitar a [documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) do Laravel sobre `attribute casting`.

Comment: Perfeito..!! no meu migration estou usando `char` e no `attribute casts` coloquei como `char` e funcionou certinho.. Vlws!!